# I added *ReSharper* to my gitignore, but compiling still shows _Resharper files when doing git status

Tags: git

I added *ReSharper* to my .gitignore files, but I'm guessing there were files that were being tracked previously that don't get deleted just by adding things to my gitignore file.

Is it possible to blow these files out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah either do `git rm` or `git rm --cached` ( if you want to keep the file but just untrack it) and then commit. Only then .gitignore will take effect on those files.

Comment: can I do that on a folder, so that all files in that folder are untracked?

Comment: @Blankman - Yeah in case of folder you will have to add `-r` flag